# Is it possible to work with data as a property?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am currently merging Sentinel and Landsat with inner join, when I do it the Landsat images are left as property in the Sentinel images. How can I fix this? Otherwise, can I work with the data from a property?

```
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filterBounds(subsubcuencas_ms);
print(s2);

var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
.filterBounds(subsubcuencas_ms);
print(l8);

var joined = ee.Join.saveAll('landsat').apply({
  primary: s2,
  secondary: l8,
  condition: ee.Filter.and(
    ee.Filter.maxDifference({
      difference: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // One day in milliseconds
      leftField: 'system:time_start',
      rightField: 'system:time_start',
    }),
    ee.Filter.intersects({
      leftField: '.geo',
      rightField: '.geo',
    })
  )
});
var band = joined.select('QA60')
print(band);
print(joined, 'joined')

// Map a function to merge the results in the output FeatureCollection.
var joinedLS = joined.map(function(image) {
  return image.cat(image.get('Landsat'));
});
print(joinedLS)
```

Answer (score 0):

The saveAll join saves the (potentially multiple) matching results in a list-typed property.  In order to merge the bands together, you need to get the image out of that list (if you know there can be only one), or convert the list of images into a single image (if there can be more than one).

Something like this:

```
// Map a function to merge the results in the output FeatureCollection.
var joinedLS = joined.map(function(image) {
  var list = ee.List(image.get('Landsat'))
  var oneImage = list.get(0)
  return image.addBands(oneImage);
});
```

Comment: I tried it, however it gives me that image.addbands is not a function of image.addbands.

Comment: You have to cast the results of the join to an ImageCollection before the map. (and (de)capitalize the 'landsat' field to match what's being set in the join).